# TeamCity configuarion for nUnit run

Tags: configuration, nunit, teamcity

I have an issue with setting up TeamCity for nUnit run and below lines are added for edit assembly files.

```
"%system.NUNIT_EXE%" 
"%env.ROOT_FOLDER%\FunctionalTests\bin\Debug\Test.dll"  /nologo
/framework=4.0.30319 /labels /xml=c:\simulator\TestBox.xml 
/fixture:Instron.Tests.Test_FunctionalTests
```

[image]

I get the error message saying when I run TeamCity.

> Failed to parse TeamCity implicit arguments. Illegal characters in
>      path.
>
> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
>
> at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
>
> at System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(String path)
>
> at JetBrains.TeamCity.Utils.FsScanner.RealFileSystem.IsPathAbsolute(String
>      path)
>
> at
>      JetBrains.TeamCity.Utils.FsScanner.DirectoryScanner.ParsePattern(IFileSystem
>      fs,
>          Wildcard[] rootPrefix, Boolean caseSensitive, String pattern)

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context before you can expect a sensible answer.  What is TeamCity for example?

Comment: Hi Neil,I have added the pic link for team_city_config page.

Comment: @Gobi are you sure that the `system.NUNIT_EXE` and `env.ROOT_FOLDER` are defined?

Comment: Hi Sergii, how do I make sure if they have  been defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the parameters in the project settings on the `Administration` page. Use the `Add new parameter` button to add the parameters for your build.

[image]

Check [the official documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Parameters) to get more information.